# Global variables aren't working

Tags: python, loops, variables, global

My global variables are not working in my code. I'm fairly new to this and I can't seem to figure this out: I have set variables (only showing gna for this), which can be manipulated by an entry field, triggered by a corresponding button. For some reason, it's not taking the changes within the loop. I'm trying to make it to where the changed variable can be graphed as well, but it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)   File "G:/PYTHON/Eulers.py", line 64, in graph
     v[i + 1] = 1 / c * (gna * f[i] - gk * u[i]) * del_t + v[i]
 TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('< U32') dtype('< U32') dtype('< U32')
```

Here is the code:

```
gna = 0.9

gnalabel = Label(topFrame, text="gna = %s" % gna)
gnalabel.pack()

gnaEntry = Entry(topFrame, justify=CENTER)
gnaEntry.pack()

def gnacallback():
    global gna
    gna = gnaEntry.get()
    gnalabel.config(text="C = %s" % gna)

gnaButton = Button(topFrame, text="Change", width=10, command=gnacallback)
gnaButton.pack()

def graph():
    global c, gna, gk, beta, gamma

    for i in range(0, len(t)-1):

        stinum = np.floor(i / 3000)
        stimt = 3000 + 3000 * (stinum - 1)

        f[i] = v[i] * (1 - (((v[i]) ** 2) / 3))
        v[i + 1] = 1 / c * (gna * f[i] - gk * u[i]) * del_t + v[i]

        if(i == stimt):
            v[i + 1] = v[i + 1] + v_stim

        u[i + 1] = (v[i] + beta - gamma * u[i]) * del_t + u[i]

    plt.plot(v)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: your code isn't very pythonic - you use unnecessary `()`

Comment: Global variables are more of a last resort kind of thing

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I don't see any. That's the least of their worries, though

Comment: please don't use thisWayOfVariableNaming. It violates PEP 8. Your variables names are bad, IMHO. what's "gna"?

Comment: learn how to make a [mcve]. click the link, you'll like it :)

Comment: Aside from agreeing with other comments, your graph() function declares globals that are not created at the top of your code.

Comment: I'm used to c++ coding, so a lot of my habits kind of move over to python. 
gNa stands for pseudo sodium.

Comment: Your code can't run in the form you have shown.  What is t? where does it come from.  Please write the least amount of code that shows your problem, and that can be run by someone who might want to help you.  Python isn't c++

Comment: @WayneWerner Global variables are more of a "first" resort kind of thing, if you're just starting out or transferring from certain `historic` programming languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gna = gnaEntry.get()
```

`Entry.get` returns a string, which is probably an unsuitable type for the arithmetic you're doing in `graph`. Try converting to a number first.

```
gna = float(gnaEntry.get()) #or perhaps `int` if it's always an integer
```

Comment: @EvelinRamos if this solves your problem you should mark the answer as accepted, using the check mark to the left